# How to connect to myslqd.socket?

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, configuration

After looging in to my ubuntu machine, I try to login to my database using the following command in the shell:

```
mysql --user=root -p
```

Then I get the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

What I have tried:

1. Uninstall and reinstall -> same error afterward.
2. `sudo service mysql start` -> Job for mysql.service failed.
3. Used [configuration template](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-configuration-file-sample) in my.cnf (which is /etc/mysql for Linux).
4. search for mysqld.sock -> The system doesn't find.

Does anybody have another solution that I could try? Thanks!

Comment: Use following command to restart `sudo service mysqld start`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to SQL by getting another droplet at digital ocean. I install SQL in the new droplet and worked like a charm. I don't understand why the other droplet was giving me that error. Thanks everyone.